# NameError: global name 'CV_GUI_NORMAL' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm coding using Python and OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04. When I click on the right button of the mouse, the associated mouse event `cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN` does not work and I rather get context menu ("actions"). Is there a way to disable the context menu popup?

A user gave me a hint and I am sure the solution is somewhere there. He asked me to add `CV_GUI_NORMAL` as shown on [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html).

So I run: `cv2.namedWindow("Window",CV_GUI_NORMAL)` but I got this error:

> NameError: global name 'CV_GUI_NORMAL' is not defined

When I try `cv2.CV_GUI_NORMAL` as on the below user's comment instead, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_GUI_NORMAL'

Note that similar question was asked [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/32633/opencv-249-highgui-qt-howto-disable-menu-right-click-context/) but I do not want to change OpenCV code.

How to fix this ?

.

Comment: Try `cv2.CV_GUI_NORMAL`

Comment: @ForceBru thank you. Check my edit if you would like.

Comment: @ForceBru  thank you but `AttributeError` again :(

Comment: some variables weren't migrated to cv2 yet, maybe this one's in cv? Check the edit please.

Comment: @ForceBru I run your third update (cv.CV_) but got same AttributeError

Comment: that probably means there's no such variable _at all_. Maybe you should use `cv2.cv.CV_GUI_EXPANDED`?

Comment: @ForceBru thank you, but same AttributeError with `CV_GUI_EXPANDED` (tested with all the former ways)

Comment: I upvote however your answer because you made lot of efforts to help me, thank you

Comment: I read the docs and rewrote the answer, maybe that'll help. Thanks a lot for upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) says:

> Python: 
>   cv.NamedWindow(name, flags=CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE) → None
>   Parameters: 
>   name – Name of the window in the window caption that may be used as a window identifier.
>   flags –
>   Flags of the window. The supported flags are:
>
> WINDOW_NORMAL If this is set, the user can resize the window (no constraint).
>
> WINDOW_AUTOSIZE If this is set, the window size is automatically adjusted to fit the displayed image (see imshow() ), and you cannot change the window size manually.
>
> WINDOW_OPENGL If this is set, the window will be created with OpenGL support.

Only some implementations with Qt backend support `CV_GUI_NORMAL`. It seems you have no choice than to install cv2 with Qt support or use other variables.

In that case you'll be using `cv2.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL`.

For a starter you could build without Qt support if you do not need it. It seems to do more harm than good in many cases. So it is better set the flag `WINDOW_OPENGL`: That way you disable the QT support and get the OpenGL one.

Comment: I must kiss you million times man ! I used the flag `WINDOW_OPENGL` so that the window gets OpenGL support instead of QT and it works so fine ! Thank you a lot

Comment: gaah, the only problem with stackoverflow is most posts links are dead :c

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL` as follows:

```
cv2.namedWindow('desired_name_of_window', flags= cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Allowed windows values in `cv2` are:

```
WINDOW_AUTOSIZE = 1
WINDOW_FREERATIO = 256
WINDOW_FULLSCREEN = 1

WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED = 0
WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL = 16

WINDOW_KEEPRATIO = 0
WINDOW_NORMAL = 0
WINDOW_OPENGL = 4096

WND_PROP_ASPECT_RATIO = 2

WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE = 1
WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN = 0
WND_PROP_OPENGL = 3
WND_PROP_VISIBLE = 4
```

Comment: Thanks! It's seems to be impossible to find these in the docs :)